# how to run a packet capturing programme in torque cluster with 2 compute node and 1 head node?

Tags: cluster-computing, jobs, pbs, qsub, torque

I configured a cluster using torque pbs with 2 compute node and 1 head node. I submitted job using qsub command like
qsub myscript.sh

myscript.sh contains some shell code . This script is executed successfully in any compute node and result i got in terms of some out put file. This type of job submission and execution is very easy. But i facing lot of problem with the following ...

I have a network packet capturing module written in C with libpcap dependency . My requirement is like that. I want to submit this programme to to different compute node(computenode-0-0, computenode-0-1). So that what ever all packet is coming to head node those packet will be processed by my programme which is running in the compute node.

How will I submit the C program? How load balancing will be done in compute node? What are the additional configuration I have to do in cluster?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question that I don't think can be answered with the information provided. Hopefully I can help at least a little bit.

Q: How do you submit the c program? 
A: Looks like you already submitted it correctly, [ qsub someProgram.sh -l walltime=x....]
If you want to interact with the program while it is running, then look at interactive jobs.
http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/2-5-12/help.htm#topics/commands/qsub.htm

Q: How is load balancing done on the compute node? 
A: Torque does not do any load balancing (exception is mom hierarchy ). Here is the life cycle of a job:
  1. job is sent to pbs_server from the submit host
  2. pbs_server sends the script to 1 of the nodes (called the mother superior)
  3. The mother superior executes the script and queries the other nodes through the TM interface. (The job does not actually run on every node)

Q: What configuration do you have to do in the cluster? 
A: Too vague.